# Django template inheritance // how to use multiple css files?

Tags: css, django

I would like to find a solution to have multiple CSS files for different templates using Django template inheritance.

So far I could extend my base.html template with another apps template. Now I would like to use a seperate css files for the apps html templates (one app = 1x html, 1x js,  1x css). But when I include the template into the template tag it replaces the css file from the base.html and crashes the site.

How can someone implement a second css file into a extended html template that only refers to the extended part and doesn't "touch" the base.html?

Thank you for your guidance in advance.

***extended html template which crashes site because of replacement of base.css file:***

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block head_css_site %}
<link href="{% static 'Quotes_app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endblock head_css_site %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Test</h1>

{% endblock %}

{% block footer_javascript_site %}
<script src="{% static 'Quotes_app.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock footer_javascript_site %}
```

***base.html:***

```
{# HTML5 declaration #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
{# Make modifiable head elements #}

<head>
  <title>{% block title %}  {% endblock title %} DASHEX </title>
  {% block head_favicon %}
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/logo.jpg">
  {% endblock head_favicon %}
  {% block head_meta %}
  {% block head_meta_charset %}
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  {% endblock head_meta_charset %}
  {% block head_meta_contentlanguage %}
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" value="en-US" />
  {% endblock head_meta_contentlanguage %}
  {% block head_meta_viewport %}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  {% endblock head_meta_viewport %}
  {% endblock head_meta %}


  {% block css %}
  {% block head_css_site %}
  <link href="{% static 'base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  {% endblock head_css_site %}
  {% endblock css %}


</head>
[...]
```

***project structure:***

[image]

Comment: ...doh. Solved by myself. I moved the stylesheet of the base.html template out of the template tag and used the template tag in the extended file to link the required css file. @mod, should I delete the post again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [a `{{ block.super }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) (search for "super") in the deriving template's block override to use both the parent content and your extension:

```
{% block head_css_site %}
{{ block.super }}
<link href="{% static 'Quotes_app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endblock head_css_site %}
```